# Additional field in option selector

Tags: php, html, sql, return, hidden

I use an option selector in this way...

```
$option = '';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row){
        $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['SpieltagIDs'].'">'.$row['Spiel'].'</option>';
    }
```

On the front I see the value of `$row['Spiel']` and after a selection I get back the value of `$row['SpieltagIDs']`. Both comes from an sql query. But I have another field in this sql query which I wanna use. How can I insert a additional field which should not be see in the fronted option selector?

Comment: The normal way is how you have it. If you need this other field, you use the `SpieltagIDs` to go an get the row from the database again when you need it in the form that is processing this form input

Comment: Try like '.$row['SpieltagIDs'].'|'.'.$row['otherField'].' And then explode it.

Comment: please show me the array..

Comment: concatenate with any special character . and in server side use explode with special character

Comment: I build it like this way .$row['SpieltagIDs'].'|'.'.$row['otherField'].' . But now I have another problem with my array. I get via print_r this array back Array ( [0] => 40;6;5;SC Freiburg - Hertha BSC [1] => Heim ) and when I execute echo ($int_array[3]); I get 0. I think this is because of a string value. What I can do to handle this problem?